# How to customize user roles in Wordpress DashBoard from PHP code?

Tags: wordpress, admin, roles, dashboard

I am customizing a part of a WordPress theme (Tiger theme). I would like to customize two roles.

I would like to see new role names in both settings screens of new user creation (*Users > Add New*) and users list (*Users > All Users*).

Which are the files that I have to modify?

Comment: "Which are the files?" Are you asking how to make this change via code or are you asking how to make this configuration change manually?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress users and roles are not kept in files, everything is stored in the database.

The function you are searching for is [add_role()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role). There are some more wp-funtions to edit the user roles: remove_role(), get_role(), add_cap() and remove_cap(). Those are pretty [well documented](https://managewp.com/create-custom-user-roles-wordpress).